# How to pad numbers to the border of the Matrix?

Tags: matlab

If I have a matrix called 'mat':

```
mat=[1,2,3,4;5,6,7,8;9,10,11,12;13,14,15,16];
```

[image]

how to pad numbers to the border of the `mat`?

for example,
if size of matrix is n=5:
the output should be:

[image]

if size of matrix is n=6:
the output should be:

[image]

In *Mathematica*,I can use this code:

```
ArrayPad[mat, {0, 2}, "Fixed"]
```

How to implement this in *Matlab*?

Comment: What is the difference between `HLmap1` and `HLmap3`? And why you use indices `(x/4+1,y/4+1)`?

Comment: Can you provide the input and output examples of what the code should do?

Right now, you are trying to access `HLmap3(xx,128/4+1)=HLmap(xx,33)` which is out of `HLmap3` dimensions.

Comment: @Crowley I edit my question and add some information about expected output

Comment: But the matrix you are trying to fill is 4x wider and 4x longer than the matrix whose elements you use in the calculations. I cannot see what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 n=6;
 padarray(mat,[n-4,n-4],'replicate','post')
```

[image]

In this case the above code is equal to *Mathematica* code:

```
ArrayPad[mat, {0, n-4}, "Fixed"]
```

And their name are very similar too.

Answer (score 0):

Partida, the problem occurs when x=1 and Y=128

You just need to re-think what you wanna accomplish. This for cycle cannot work the way it is because of the size matter.

Make a condition for Y=128.
If y=128, then you don't sum "+1" for the index.

```
load lis
sumLumi=HLmap1;
for x=1:size(HLmap1,1)
   for y=1:size(HLmap1,2)
           if (y~=size(HLmap1,2)
sumLumi(x,y)=HLmap3(floor(x/4)+1,floor(y/4)+1)+HLmap3(floor(x/4)+2,floor(y/4)+1)+HLmap3(floor(x/4)+1,floor(y/4)+2)+HLmap3(floor(x/4)+2,floor(y/4)+2);
else
sumLumi(x,y)=HLmap3(floor(x/4),floor(y/4))+HLmap3(floor(x/4),floor(y/4))+HLmap3(floor(x/4),floor(y/4))+HLmap3(floor(x/4)+2,floor(y/4));
       end
    end
    sumLumi
```

Comment: The problem occurs for `x=1` and `y=128`.